# I want to know how to properly use the read() and open() functions in unix

Tags: c

I want to ask you about `read()`.

I just use it like this:

```
 char array[10] = {'\0',};
 read(0,array,sizeof(array));
```

Here insert something in console "abc.txt" and then maybe an array is stored with:

```
 a[0] = a
 a[1] = b
 a[2] = c
 a[3] = .
 a[4] = t
 a[5] = x
 a[6] = t
 a[7] = \0
 a[8] = \0
 a[9] = \0
```

and I will use the `open` function:

```
 open(array,~);
```

I think it doesn't work.  //dd

What I meant to happen is for the `open` function to recognize `abc.txt\0`
but it maybe actually recognizes `abc.txt\0\0\0\0`

How can I improve my code that `open()` function works as I want?

Comment: `open()` takes a C string, so it will stop at the first `\0`. What exactly is the problem you're seeing? and what is `~` supposed to be in your `open()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the result of `open()`.  Without it, code does not know if the `\0` are from the `read()` call or the initialization `array[10] = {'\0',}`

```
ssize_t len = read(0,array,sizeof(array));
// Use `len` as then needed.
```